# Non-Ivalue in assignment error

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I'm getting the above error message twice during compile time. Everything else works fine i.e no other compile time errors. This is a simple binary tree program and the function where the errors are coming from is a swap or mirror function meant to simply to swap all subtrees. Here is the function

```
template <class dataType>
void swapSubTrees ( BinaryTree <dataType> * bt )
{
    if(bt == NULL)
    {
        //do nothing  
    }
    else
    {  
        swapSubTrees(bt->left());
        swapSubTrees(bt->right());
        BinaryTree <int> *temp;
        temp = bt->left();
        bt->left() = bt->right();
        bt->right() = temp;
   }
}
```

and here is my function call in the main (this is where I get the two non-lvalue errors

```
swapSubTrees (b1);
```

b1 is an object instantiated from class BinaryTree and it is at the top of my tree. There are corresponding objects b2,b3,b4 and b5 which are other nodes of the tree, obviously from code that I have left out.
Anyway I cannot seem to find where I went wrong, what could it be? Any help would be great thanks!
and the left function looks like

```
Template <class dataType>
BinaryTree <dataType> * BinaryTree<dataType> :: left()
{
    return leftTree;
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to call swapSubTrees<dataType>(bt->left()); etc

Comment: what does `left()` and `right()` look like?

Comment: I will add to my question

Comment: i'd suggest swaping `if(bt == NULL)` with `if(bt != NULL)` and skip your current `then` clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the lines that give the errors are:

```
bt->left() = bt->right();
bt->right() = temp;
```

?

You can't use a function call like that as the left hand side of an expression.

---

Add this method to the BinaryTree template class:

```
template<class dataType>
void BinaryTree<dataType>::swapChildren()
{
    BinaryTree *tmp = leftTree;
    leftTree = rightTree;
    rightTree = tmp;

    if (leftTree)
        leftTree->swapChildren();
    if (rightTree)
        rightTree->swapChildren();
}
```

Then change your free-function to simply be:

```
template <class dataType>
void swapSubTrees ( BinaryTree <dataType> * bt )
{
    if(bt != NULL)
        bt->swapChildren();
}
```

Comment: You *can* if it returns a non-const reference, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Or if it returns a class type.

Comment: so then what do i do? :(

Comment: you could use setters (`setLeft` and `setRight` if they're provided), or make the function a friend and hit the members without the accessor functions. But were it me I would make a node method called `swapChildren()` that does what you're doing now, but in the context of the class, then just fire it on the passed in node pointer and let *it* do it for you. Let the node(s) swap their own kids.

Comment: so basically if I just make this function as a member of the node class then the syntax would be fine?

Comment: @user2710184 pretty much. If you want to keep the free-function its your choice. I've updated this answer to include an example. Hope the author doesn't mind. It assumes your members are `leftTree` and `rightTree`. I doubt they are, so use the appropriate ids. Hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Add

`void setLeft( BinaryTree <dataType> * other );`

and

`void setRight( BinaryTree <dataType> * other );`

To your BinaryTree class, assuming they don't already exist (I'll leave the implementation of those to you!)

then change the erroring lines to

```
bt->setLeft( bt->right() );
bt->setRight( temp );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to assign a value to an `rvalue`.

Essentially, the cause is that the value returned by `left` and `right` is a temporary object. You're returning a copy of the pointer, and this copy cannot be assigned to.

The way to get this to compile is to change the `left` and `right` functions to return a reference to your pointer, which can be assigned to. This is done as follows:

```
Template <class dataType>
BinaryTree <dataType>*& BinaryTree<dataType> :: left()
{
    return leftTree;
}
```

(And similarly for `right`)

Note the ampersand (&) after the asterisk (*). This means the returned value is a reference. This is called returning by reference, rather than returning by value.

Now, this would cause the code to compile. But you really should ask yourself if this is what you want. Do you want someone from outside to be allowed to change what `leftTree` points to inside the `BinaryTree`?

A better option would likely be to add a setter function for these two, and call these instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you will rewrite your functions left() and right() as returning reference to pointer then there will not be a problem.:)

Comment: my left and right functions are used in other places in my program will this have an effect? and I am not sure what you mean by returning reference to pointer :/ could please explain

Comment: I'd really avoid this!

Comment: For example BinaryTree<int> * & left(); But there is another approach is to write function that sets BinaryTree *,